# why do I get this message: “Installer“ wants access to control “SystemUIServer“

Tags: macos, install, catalina, pkg

I get a popup with the following text:

> “Installer“ wants access to control “SystemUIServer“ ...

with option to allow / not allow.

every single time I install an app from a pkg file

why do I get this message? and why would the installer need that access? Furthermore, there is no way to grant this access in the settings.

Comment: Do you have any third-party menulets in the menu bar?

Comment: yes: docker, go for gmail, alfred, magnet, tresorit, haptic key, time machine + the classic sound, wifi, etc

Comment: It's likely that one of those is causing it.

Comment: what would be the reason? I can proceed by elimination and try to see which one causes it

Comment: if anyone wonders, I found and it's part of the installer for games released by GoG as it is looking for the /Application/Games folder. The script can be checked out and it's all ok to accept.